# Delivery Window timing

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, send-email, send-throttling

When I set up an email with a Delivery Window of say 8-3 and a throttle of 1K/hr, will there be a 1K batch sent at 3pm or will 2pm be the last batch?

Similarly, I assume I can start the send immediately or schedule it for say 6am but no emails will send until 8am, yes?

Any weird caveats or things to keep in mind when using the Delivery Window and throttling together?

Answer (score 2):

A throttle window wouldn't happen after the end time, An email wouldn't be sent after 3 in this case.

Inversely emails won't send before the window is open

Caveats is to ensure no one one is in the queue for longer than 72hrs, otherwise they will error and not send